# What happened to jabber / hangouts options in messages?

Tags: mojave, messages, jabber

Messages (on Mac OS X) used to let you add a gmail account for jabber -- it appears this is gone now? Is there a way to **re-enable** it?

Comment: In addition to Hangouts, Jabber was also removed from messages in Mojave.

Comment: Oh, wait, so in 10.13 and earlier, the old option for Google Talk still works with modern Google Hangouts? That is _great_, I did not know that!

Answer (score 0):

Jabber and Google Hangouts was removed from Messages in Mojave. You might consider using [Adium](https://adium.im/).

Answer (score 0):

The last macOS to support Jabber in Messsages version 11.0 was High Sierra macOS 10.13.x. Messages version 12 on macOS 10.14.x Mojave removed the ability to add Jabber accounts. Earlier versions of Messages called iMessages and iChat before that allowed one to add ICQ/AIM/Jabber/XMPP accounts.

It is possible to downgrade by backing up your data and re-installing High Sierra but you would likely be better off finding a different Jabber client. Adium, Pidgin, AstraChat, etc.